# Did Leia ever meet Ahsoka through the Rebellion?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, princess-leia, ahsoka-tano

**Spoiler warning for *Rebels*.**

This is about when Ahsoka was working with the Rebellion, not after Rebels.

In the Ahsoka novel, there is a brief scene where Ahsoka hears Bail talking to a young Leia.  This is around the time Ahsoka tells Bail that she's going to join the Rebellion.  This book takes place, according to Wookieepedia, one year after the events of *Revenge of the Sith*.

In *Rebels*, we learn about how Ahsoka is helping the Rebellion, and we also see how Leia is as well, working with her father, Bail.  Given that the two both worked with the Rebellion and with Bail Organa, is there any evidence that they ever met?  Ahsoka wouldn't have known about Leia's true parentage, but she could've known her simply as another Rebel and as Bail's daughter.

Comment: In the Ahsoka novel, Bail is reasonably clear that he wants to keep Leia and Ahsoka at arms length; "*The casual way she had talked about Anakin and Padmé made him think that she might have known the true nature of their relationship but not the outcome. He was sure she didn’t know about Leia, about the boy. ... Having someone else lead the search would work out well for him, too. Every layer of deception between him and anything connected to the Force was another layer in the safety net he was building for his daughter.*"

Comment: So Bail was talking to a one year old Leia right?

Answer (score 3):

As Valorum commented, **Bail did want to keep them apart**. Ahsoka was a very important Rebel operative and it was **likely that the two met at some point or another**, in a war council or over a holo-transmission. This would make some sense but I believe that Bail would have set himself or someone other than Leia as Ahsoka's point of contact, and seeing as Leia *is* in Rebels, the two might have met, but I think if this happened Bail would have at least **warned Ahsoka of Leia's identity and the importance that this was not to be revealed**. And seeing as in RotJ, Leia has no idea of her identity except for a sense of belonging when it *is* revealed, **if the two met they did not discuss Anakin  or Padme Skywalker** and their relationship would have been as colleagues, and probably not friends (as that could lead to Ahsoka letting something slip).

Comment: Do you think that Bail would've told Ahsoka about Leia's parentage?  It doesn't seem like, in TCW, that Ahsoka even knew that Anakin and Padme were married, let alone that they had kids.  In Rebels, Ahsoka already doesn't go into detail about her past, so it seems like, if they met, given what Ahsoka doesn't know, there wouldn't be an explicit danger, especially if Bail took care not to have them interact one-on-one.

Comment: I'm just extrapolating the different sources. Disney has made it clear that she somehow knows and I'm trying to give reasonable options as to why that is.

Comment: Sorry if I'm coming off as agressive; I'm just genuinely interested in discussing this - where did Disney make it clear that Ahsoka knows?  Has Ahsoka ever mentioned anything that makes it known that she knew about Luke and Leia's parentage?

Comment: Not that she knew explicitly that Luke and Leia were the children of Anakin Skywalker but she knew that Anakin fell to the Dark Side because of his feelings for Padme. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, in the Mandalorian season 2, she says "I've seen what feelings have done to a fully trained jedi knight" (I might have gotten that a little incorrect). This shows that she knew what happened to Anakin at the very least....  see my answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243562/how-did-ahsoka-know-the-specifics-of-anakins-fall)